# How Map stores keys

Tags: javascript, lit-html, es6-map

I was reading about lit-html and how it works [here](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/wiki/How-it-Works).

But i could not understand how they can use the `strings` argument as cache-key. 
I have read about Map in mdn but i didnt found anything that explains how Map `get` and `set` works.

My question how the argument `strings` can be used as key. Basically how Map stores keys because keys can be anything.

```js
// Store how many times we've seen each literal
let counts = new Map();

// A template tag that updates the count storage and longs the count
let count = (strings) => {
  // The strings object is our Map key
  let c = (counts.get(strings) || 0) + 1;
  counts.set(strings, c);
  console.log(`literal ${strings.join('')} seen ${c} time(s)`);
};

// Two functions that evaluate to different tagged literals
let f = (text) => count`abc`;
let g = (text) => count`def`;

f();
f();
g();
```

Comment: A map...works. It's a generic [well known datastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), so the ES6 implementation is nothing more than introducing a default built-in of this datastructure. Well, a different one than plain objects, since `{abc: 2, def: 1}` is also fundamentally a hash/map/hashmap but only slightly more limited in some ways (can't have many types for keys) but has other advantages like prototypal inheritance. However, as a data structure, they are the same.

Comment: That things i know about Map. But i am trying understand how it sets the key when the key is not a string or primittive value. For example, how it finds the correct key/value pair when the key is an array (`map.set([1,2,3], 'myvalue')`)

Comment: The same way you'd set it in a normal array, really. `arr = []; key = [1, 2, 3]; arr.push(key); arr.includes(key); /* true */ arr.includes([1, 2, 3]); /* false */` You get the same behaviour with maps - they still do a normal comparison via (essentially) `===` since `map.set([1,2,3], 'myvalue'); map.get([1, 2, 3])` will not return `'myvalue'`.

Comment: So it compares the values and the reference of the key when they are non primitive values? So, my question is when the `count` is called the `strings` argument has his own reference and how each call (of the `count` function) points to same reference?. If i understand correctly when a function is called its created new local execution context, so the argument `strings` has different refrence. Correct if im wrong please. And Thanks

Comment: All variables in JavaScript are [pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language), so two strings *with the same content* are always equal: `"ab" === "a" + "b" //true`. All primitive values exhibit this behaviour...well, Symbols are different but that's by design. Objects (which includes functions and arrays) are *also* pass-by-value. However, the *value* of an object variable is its reference. So, `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = [1, 2, 3]` point to two different arrays, let's say ref `0xAAA` and ref `0xBBB`. When you do `a === b`,

Comment: you're actually checking if the ref `0xAAA` is equal to the ref `0xBBB`. Since they are not, they point to two different memory locations and thus two different objects, thus they are not equal. An object is therefore only equal to itself: `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = a;` would set `a` to the reference `0xAAA` and `b` will also hold `0xAAA` now (pointing at the same object). Thus `a === b` is checking if `0xAAA` is `0xAAA` and that's true. So, don't confuse how primitive values and objects are compared - *technically*, it's the same but for a different reason and a different result than you'd expect.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for the clarification. Could you elaborate the last part "it's the same but for a different reason and a different result than you'd expect" please. I dont understant it.

Comment: Again, JavaScript is always pass-by-value. So you're always doing value comparison whether you compare primitives or objects, so `x === y` will do the exact same operation in either case. From a technical standpoint - the same. Yet the behaviour seems different - `"foo" === "foo"` and `["f", "o", "o"] === ["f", "o", "o"]` produce different results to what one might expect, since many assume that an object's value is the data the object (currently) holds.